# i cant start the function outside of the function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to start the animation without the button in the script or i want that the animation start when its loaded

```
const slotMachine = {
    data: function () {
    return {
      slots: [{
        title: "Backend",
        items: [
          "Jeremias Badilla",
          "Miguel Cornejo Labra",
          "Fabian General",
          "Claudio Guerra",
          "Camilo Jorquera",
          "Ivan Nawrath Castilo"
        ]
      }],
      opts: null,
      startedAt: null
    }
  },
  template: `
<div class='slot-machine'>
  <div class='slot' v-for='slot in slots' ref='slots'>
    <h2 class="slot__title">Code Contest: {{ slot.title }}</h2>
    <div class='slot__window'>
      <div class='slot__wrap'>
        <div class='slot__item' v-for='opt in slot.items'>{{ opt }}</div>
        <div class='slot__item slot__item--copy' >{{ slot.items[0] }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="slot__button" @click='start'>Sortear</button>
</div>`,
  methods: {
    start: function() {
        if (this.opts) {
        return
      }         
      this.opts = this.slots.map( (data, i) => {
        const slot = this.$refs.slots[i]
        const choice = Math.floor( Math.random() * data.items.length )
        const opts = {
          el: slot.querySelector('.slot__wrap'),
          finalPos: choice * 180,
          startOffset: 9000 + Math.random() * 500 + i * 500,
          height: data.items.length * 180,
          duration: 9000 + i * 700, // milliseconds
          isFinished: false
        }
        return opts
      })
      next(this.animate)
    },
    animate: function(timestamp) {
            if (this.startedAt == null) {
        this.startedAt = timestamp
      }
      const timeDiff = timestamp - this.startedAt
      this.opts.forEach( opt => {
        if (opt.isFinished) {
            return
        }
        const timeRemaining = Math.max(opt.duration - timeDiff, 0)
        const power = 3
        const offset = ( Math.pow(timeRemaining, power) / Math.pow(opt.duration, power) ) * opt.startOffset
        // negative, such that slots move from top to bottom
        const pos = -1 * Math.floor((offset + opt.finalPos) % opt.height)
        opt.el.style.transform = "translateY(" + pos + "px)"
        if ( timeDiff > opt.duration ) {
            opt.isFinished = true
        }
      })
      if (this.opts.every( o => o.isFinished )) {
        this.opts = null
        this.startedAt = null
      } else {
        next( this.animate )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i want that it starts without clicking @click="start"

i try a lot but its says allways that this.slots.map is not defined

i try next( this.start ) to start in the code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't it vue.js?

Comment: can be its from https://codepen.io/juanbrujo/pen/BGXGOe

Comment: @Konrad yes! thanks a lot the mount is what im search for!